# Motion Vectors and DCT residuals, are they related or independent?

Tags: h.264, video-encoding

I am working on a novel technique that uses already encoded H264 motion vectors from a pre-encoded video.

I need to know how the motion vectors and residuals are related. I need some very specific answers that I can't find answered anywhere else:

1. Are the motion vectors forward, or backward? I mean, does the vector indicate where the current 4x4 or 8x8, 8x4 .... block will be in the next frame **(forward)**. Or is it the opposite? (That in the block it is indicated where that block comes from), **(backwards)**.
2. In the case a block has multiple references (I don't know if that is even possible). How are those references added together? Mean? Weighted?
3. How is the residual error being compensated, per block (4x8, 8x4, etc)? Ignoring the sub blocks, and just partitioning the image in 8x8 chunks?

My ultimate goal, is to know from the video feed the "accuracy" of each motion vector. I can only do that with backwards prediction, and if the DCT residuals are per block. In that case I can measure the accuracy of the motion vector estimation by measuring the amount of residual error of that block.

Thanks in advance!!
PD: Reading trough the 800 pages of H264 is not easy task....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The H264 standard is your friend.  Also get the books by Ian Richardson, a bit more readable than the standard (but only a bit :)

"Are the motion vectors forward, or backward?" - they are backward.  The MV for a block points to where that block came from.

"In the case a block has multiple references (I don't know if that is even possible). How are those references added together?" - it is possible, check out weightb and weightp options for x264.  Can have up to two references, the explicit weights are encoded in the stream (I *think* as deltas from the neighbor weights, so usually zeros - but don't quote me on that; also I think whether weights are used is a flag somewhere, if not used the weights are equal by default)

"How is the residual error being compensated" - depends on the macroblock partitioning mode and transform size.  The MVs are for each partition, the residuals are for the transform size tiled into the partition (so if a 16x16 is partitioned into two 16x8 and the transform is 8x8, each partition gets two transforms; if the transform is 4x4 each partition gets (16/4)x(8/4)=8 transforms).

For experiments, you can change encoder settings to turn off B-frames and weighted P-frames, and also restrict the partitioning mode to not partition (ie 16x16 only).  This allows much easier way to try different motion vectors :)

Comment: Thanks! I currently have this project in stand-by. But it is a legit answer